# Cocoa Touch. Why does NSNumber return a difference value for intValue and floatValue?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnumber

Ok, this makes absolutely no sense:

I creat an NSNumber:

```
NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithInt:37669178];
```

I then echo the value as an integer and a float:

```
int i = [n intValue];  
float f = [n floatValue];
```

Here are their values:

```
int: 37669178  
float: 37669176.000000
```

Huh!?!?!

Could someone please explain to me why this is happening and how to get around it. This surely cannot be a precision issue. 37,669,178 is well within the precision of a float.

Thanks,
Doug

### UPDATE

OK, Now I'm totally confused. Refering to math.h

```
#define MAXFLOAT    ((float)3.40282346638528860e+38)
```

Integer value 37669178 is 3.7669178e+7, well within the maximum allowable floating point value. So, [n floatValue] should return 37669178.0 **not** 37669176.0

What am I missing here?

Comment: This is somewhat quibbling, but "Well within the precision of a float" doesn't make much sense. The actual granularity of a `float`'s representable values varies depending on the range you check on.

Comment: You are correct. I should have said range. Great. Now do you have an answer for me or not?

Answer (score 8):

A float only has 23 bits of *precision* (not to be confused with *range*) which is around 7 significant decimal digits. Use `double` if you need more precision than this.

[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating Point](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

Related to the subject at hand: NSNumber is not intended to do precision mathematical operations with. It's just a means of wrapping a number in an object. If you require precision, you should employ NSDecimal instead.